# What is the term used for saying if something increases/decreases it has no effect on another thing

Tags: word-choice

What is the mathematical term used for saying if something increases/decreases it has no effect on another thing?

I was thinking along the lines of "X is not linear with Y" however it seems to give the sense that if X increase, Y will increase (though not linearly). This is not the idea I want to convey.

I want the reader to know that an increase/decrease in X does not necessarily mean an increase/decrease in Y.

Well, if you've read the above paragraph you know what I want, but I need the whole idea of that paragraph packed in a single phrase. (I'd have thought a mathematical term would be useful in this sense (since those words are cool), but that's not compulsory of course).

To be sure, I'm not asking for a mathematical term. I'm asking for a catchy term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Orthogonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality)

Comment: brilliant! btw how do i use it in a sentence.. X is orthogonal to Y.. X is orthogonal of Y..?

Comment: X is orthogonal to Y, or X and Y are orthogonal.

Answer (score 12):

"Is not dependent on" and "is independent of" are both common usage in statistics.

I'd also suggest "X and Y are not [correlated](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/correlate)."  This is also a commonly used term in stats.

Alternatively, you could use "X and Y are uncorrelated" (as was suggested by Alain), which means the same thing, but might sound a bit more sophisticated.

Comment: +1, that's the best word. Or better: X and Y are **uncorrelated** (just being nit-picky).

Comment: If there isn't much of any association between X and Y, and you're not explaining the statistics, you might just say they're _unrelated_. "Cell phone minutes used and bananas consumed are unrelated."

Comment: @aedia for me, **unrelated** is the best answer.  Good one.

Comment: Uncorrelated is not only the correct mathematical term, it should also be understood by non-mathematicians.

Comment: @aedia, @Joe Blow: I agree with you, but evidently OP wants something "catchy" (by which I think he means he would like to sound technical and jargony, while still being understandable).  For that, I have to admit that *uncorrelated* best fits the bill.  *Independent* (which I also think is a fine choice) is perhaps somewhere in between.

Comment: @John: you find 'correlated' _less_ technical than 'independent'? Both have their technical meanings, and both their everyday intuitive meanings; of the latter, 'independent' (changing one doesn't change the other) seems to match the OP better (actually I have to admit, 'uncorrelated' doesn't really have much of a non-technical meaning for me).

Comment: @Mitch: No, I feel *independent* is between *unrelated* (least technical-sounding) and *uncorrelated* (most technical-sounding).

Comment: @John: yes, sorry, I misread. From least to most technical:  unrelated < independent < uncorrelated.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's actually independent. X is an independent variable if it does not depend on Y.

Answer (score 2):

I would use *depend*, as in:

> Y does not depend on X.

Comment: I was thinking the other way around: X is independent of Y. I think these are both correct.

Comment: `Y does not depend on X` has zero catchyness..

Comment: @Pacerier But accurate and clear, right?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of expressing the relationship between two variables, including those in other answers. Another is with "proportional". Some examples of its use:

> - X is directly proportional to Y (i.e. as X increases or decreases, Y does so as well)
> - X is inversely proportional to Y (i.e. as X increases, Y decreases, or vice versa)
> - X is not proportional to Y (i.e. X and Y are unrelated)

This is probably the most precise way to describe two variables' relationship. There are [many other types of proportionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_%28mathematics%29).

Another expression is "direct variation", e.g.:

> - X is in direct variation with Y
> - X and Y vary directly (i.e. the value of Y depends on the value of X)
> - X is in not in direct variation with Y
> - X and Y do not vary directly (i.e. the value of Y does not depend on  the value of X)